# Wordpress Revolution Slider Transition Speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

I am trying to implement a really fast slider speed. However in the admin for the slider revolution that fastest you can make it is 100. (The duration of the transition (Default:300, min: 100 max 2000).) Do you know where in the code I can change the min? Or can I overwrite it with static code and change the speed there? Thanks in advance for your help!

- M

Comment: Nevermind - all good.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version (up 4.2+) you have now "no transform" transition also available, and the speed can be set now from 0 - unlimited also.  I would recommend to update to the latest version 4.6.5 to have all new features and option available !